# How to join two objects into array?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, arrays

I'm very new to asp net, I'm trying to return an array like this:

```
[
    {Option: 'Yes', Total: 10},
    {Option: 'No', Total: 8}
]
```

I have these two objects:

```
var op1 = new
{
    Option = "Yes",
    Total = 10
};
var op2 = new
{
    Option = "No",
    Total = 8
};

var ret = ???

return Json(ret, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you declare a class that has members of Option and Total and make a serializer so that this makes more sense? Otherwise that op1 and op2 aren't given a specific type that may be where there are issues here.

Comment: @JBKing. Because both `Total` actually are something like `ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Item > Number).Count()`

Comment: http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm would be an example of what I mean here that may help you. Notice how they have "Product" as a type that is defined and makes things much easier here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
var r= new []{op1,op2};
```

Check in this [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384090.aspx) *Implicitly-typed Arrays in Object Initializers* section.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`var ret = [op1,op2];`

Comment: `op1` and `op2` received a red underline with this message: `; expected`